# Check if variable exists in Model-Glue

Tags: coldfusion, model-glue

How can I determine whether a variable exists in Model-Glue II? I'm passing a checkbox (value = 1) via form submission. This done in Controller.cfc within a method that works already for other variables being submitted.

Test A:

```
<cfif IsDefined("arguments.event.getValue('foobar')")>

</cfif>
```

**Error: Parameter 1 of function IsDefined, which is now arguments.event.getValue('foobar'), must be a syntactically valid variable name.**

Test B (assuming M.G. implicitly creates variable with blank/NULL value):

```
<cfset foo = arguments.event.getValue('foobar') />
<cfif IsNumeric(foo) AND foo GT 0>
  // Code here
</cfif>
```

**Error: Element FOO is undefined in ARGUMENTS.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MG Docs](http://docs.model-glue.com/wiki/ReferenceMaterials/EventApi#GetValuename%3astringdefault%3aany) getValue() should return "any".  I'm guessing that means that when something just plain doesn't exist that it returns void.

However, it does have an optional second param to set a default. So you could do this:

```
<cfset foo = arguments.event.getValue('foobar', -1) />
<cfif IsNumeric(foo) AND foo GT 0>
    // Code here
</cfif>
```

If you're on CF9 you could also try using the isNull() function. But I do not know if it would work in this situation.

Comment: *facepalm* How could I forget that optional attribute?

Comment: getValue() actually returns an empty string if the variable does not exist in the Model Glue event

Comment: It's weird that he's getting that error then. Perhaps an older version?

Answer (score 2):

> `ValueExists(name:string)`
>
> **Description:**
>
> Does a value of the given name exist in the viewstate?
>
> **Returns:**
>
> Boolean
>
> **Arguments:**
>
> Name (required) - The name of the value to check

http://docs.model-glue.com/wiki/ReferenceMaterials/EventApi#ValueExistsname:string